# How to get Azure Logic App Outbound IP addresses in pipeline

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to whitelist a **logic app** through Azure SQL server firewall, for that in **Azure DevOps Pipeline**, I need to get its or its connector's **outbound ip addresses**, for webapps usually I use this **powershell** command:

```
(Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroup <group_name> -name <app_name>).OutboundIpAddresses
```

How do I achieve the same thing for a logic app/ api connector. I also read that the ips for logic apps are the same per region, is there a **powershell** command to get those ips and avoid hardcoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way:

```
$myLogicApp = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "<your-resourcegroup-name>" -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceName "<your-logic-app-name>"

$myLogicApp.Properties.endpointsConfiguration.workflow.outgoingIpAddresses

$myLogicApp.Properties.endpointsConfiguration.connector.outgoingIpAddresses
```

Comment: I would use the newer `Az` module instead of `AzureRm`.